# highlight a row in grid using ext js 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm trying to highlight a row and I've googled for a while however all solutions use functions that don't even exist such as `getRow()` or `highlight()`.

Does anyone have a solution for it?
I've tried the above and the `getView().select(record)`
Neither has worked

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Would selecting the row suffice?

```
gridPanel.getSelectionModel().select([recordToSelect]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rowClass to modify a row based on record conditions.

```
yourGrid.getView().getRowClass = function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){ 
     return record.get('status').toLowerCase(); // class selection condition
}
```

See the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/K68Dd/1/)** example for this (*very basic example, just show that the row class get ressetted after each change of the record.*)

Comment: Sounds like implementing something already implemented..or isn't it?

Comment: @user1432779 You have two ways; just select a row as @CD.. mentioned or modify the row style by changing the class and that is exactly for what the `getRowClass` method is; changing row style based on specific condition. An equal example exist for a cell; the `renderer` that can be set in a column cfg.

Comment: @user1432779 For the sake of completeness; a method that just highlight a row based on is rowindex or recerod does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0)
```

Comment: Then why would you post it?

Comment: look, my answer could select only the first row where urs one has broad scope..... finally urs one is better answer.